# Vue.js 2.3.2 version mismatch

Tags: npm, vue.js

After running `npm run watch` in terminal on my php laravel project I got this error:

```
Module build failed: Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.3.2
- vue-template-compiler@2.2.6

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.
```

I tried to run this command `npm update vue-template-compiler` but the error remained.

Did somebody else meet with this problem?

Comment: try `npm install vue-template-compiler`

Comment: Thx for the answer, but unfortunately It didn't help.

Comment: still the same error? or what do you get?

Comment: yeah.. same error unfortunately

Comment: Ohh I found a solution! check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the soluiton, I had to delete the `node_modules` folder, after I had to run `npm install` then the problem is solved.

Comment: I don't believe this is an acceptable answer considering you didn't post your package.json file. 

At least post the versions of vue nad vue-template-compiler that are there.

Comment: I figured it out, the versions of vue and vue-template-compiler have to be the same ... what a surprise :D